# Sorting divs by an attribute with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks

I have this HTML:

```
​<div indice="1">first</div>
<div indice="3">third</div>
<div indice="2">second</div>

<button onclick="organize();">Sort</button>
```

I need that when I click in button the same html to be sort asc using the atrributte "indice" and the dom become look like this:

```
​<div indice="1">first</div>
<div indice="2">second</div>
<div indice="3">third</div>
```

Comment: What did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: I wonder if there is any alternative to do this without using a loop through all the elements behind the lowest "index" and saving it (append) in an invisible div and make it to the end of the loop, always seeking the lowest, and then placing invisible layer ordered substituting visible. Jquery to offer a resource for this, which is not found, leave the code cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using javascripts array sort method

```
$('div').sort(function(a,b){
    return $(a).attr('indice') - $(b).attr('indice');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nPbk8/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the (untested by me) code from this link:
[james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/)

you just have to replace the .text() in the comparing function with
the .attr('indice')

if this is not solving your problem let me answer in a few hours when I'll be
on my laptop where I have a code snippet that does exactly what you want.